# Owl Carousel v2.3.0 en móvil impide hacer scroll hacia abajo en la página

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3

a ver si me podeis ayudar porque estoy desesperado.

Os comento un poquito por encima, estoy utilizando esta plantilla de boostrap y lleva implementado el slider Owl Carousel v2.3.0.
El problema esta a la hora de ver esta plantilla en vista móvil. El section que contiene el slider a la hora de deslizar con el dedo la pagina hacia abajo no funciona, es decir, es como si en esa parte de la pantalla no funcionara debido al slider que no tiene la función tactil verticalemente.

Os dejo la demo para que veais que no se puede interactuar con el tactil del movil.

https://colorlib.com/preview/#pizza

PD: me he revisado el JS y CSS de arriba abajo y no encuentro el fallo.

Archivo JS:

```
!function (a, b, c, d) {
    function e(b, c) {
        this.settings = null, this.options = a.extend({}, e.Defaults, c), this.$element = a(b), this._handlers = {}, this._plugins = {}, this._supress = {}, this._current = null, this._speed = null, this._coordinates = [], this._breakpoint = null, this._width = null, this._items = [], this._clones = [], this._mergers = [], this._widths = [], this._invalidated = {}, this._pipe = [], this._drag = {
            time: null,
            target: null,
            pointer: null,
            stage: {start: null, current: null},
            direction: null
        }, this._states = {
            current: {},
            tags: {initializing: ["busy"], animating: ["busy"], dragging: ["interacting"]}
        }, a.each(["onResize", "onThrottledResize"], a.proxy(function (b, c) {
            this._handlers[c] = a.proxy(this[c], this)
        }, this)), a.each(e.Plugins, a.proxy(function (a, b) {
            this._plugins[a.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + a.slice(1)] = new b(this)
        }, this)), a.each(e.Workers, a.proxy(function (b, c) {
            this._pipe.push({filter: c.filter, run: a.proxy(c.run, this)})
        }, this)), this.setup(), this.initialize()
    }

    e.Defaults = {
        items: 3,
        loop: !1,
        center: !1,
        rewind: !1,
        mouseDrag: !0,
        touchDrag: !0,
        pullDrag: !0,
        freeDrag: !1,
        margin: 0,
        stagePadding: 0,
        merge: !1,
        mergeFit: !0,
        autoWidth: !1,
        startPosition: 0,
        rtl: !1,
        smartSpeed: 250,
        fluidSpeed: !1,
        dragEndSpeed: !1,
        responsive: {},
        responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
        responsiveBaseElement: b,
        fallbackEasing: "swing",
        info: !1,
        nestedItemSelector: !1,
        itemElement: "div",
        stageElement: "div",
        refreshClass: "owl-refresh",
        loadedClass: "owl-loaded",
        loadingClass: "owl-loading",
        rtlClass: "owl-rtl",
        responsiveClass: "owl-responsive",
        dragClass: "owl-drag",
        itemClass: "owl-item",
        stageClass: "owl-stage",
        stageOuterClass: "owl-stage-outer",
        grabClass: "owl-grab"
    }, e.Width = {Default: "default", Inner: "inner", Outer: "outer"}, e.Type = {
        Event: "event",
        State: "state"
    }, e.Plugins = {}, e.Workers = [{
        filter: ["width", "settings"], run: function () {
            this._width = this.$element.width()
        }
    }, {
        filter: ["width", "items", "settings"], run: function (a) {
            a.current = this._items && this._items[this.relative(this._current)]
        }
    }, {
        filter: ["items", "settings"], run: function () {
            this.$stage.children(".cloned").remove()
        }
    }, {
        filter: ["width", "items", "settings"], run: function (a) {
            var b = this.settings.margin || "", c = !this.settings.autoWidth, d = this.settings.rtl,
                e = {width: "auto", "margin-left": d ? b : "", "margin-right": d ? "" : b};
            !c && this.$stage.children().css(e), a.css = e
        }
    }, {
        filter: ["width", "items", "settings"], run: function (a) {
            var b = (this.width() / this.settings.items).toFixed(3) - this.settings.margin, c = null,
                d = this._items.length, e = !this.settings.autoWidth, f = [];
            for (a.items = {
                merge: !1,
                width: b
            }; d--;) c = this._mergers[d], c = this.settings.mergeFit && Math.min(c, this.settings.items) || c, a.items.merge = c > 1 || a.items.merge, f[d] = e ? b * c : this._items[d].width();
            this._widths = f
        }
    }, {
        filter: ["items", "settings"], run: function () {
            var b = [], c = this._items, d = this.settings, e = Math.max(2 * d.items, 4),
                f = 2 * Math.ceil(c.length / 2), g = d.loop && c.length ? d.rewind ? e : Math.max(e, f) : 0, h = "",
                i = "";
            for (g /= 2; g > 0;) b.push(this.normalize(b.length / 2, !0)), h += c[b[b.length - 1]][0].outerHTML, b.push(this.normalize(c.length - 1 - (b.length - 1) / 2, !0)), i = c[b[b.length - 1]][0].outerHTML + i, g -= 1;
            this._clones = b, a(h).addClass("cloned").appendTo(this.$stage), a(i).addClass("cloned").prependTo(this.$stage)
        }
    }, {
        filter: ["width", "items", "settings"], run: function () {
            for (var a = this.settings.rtl ? 1 : -1, b = this._clones.length + this._items.length, c = -1, d = 0, e = 0, f = []; ++c  c; c++) a = this._coordinates[c - 1] || 0, b = Math.abs(this._coordinates[c]) + f * e, (this.op(a, "", h) || this.op(b, "", h)) && i.push(c);
            this.$stage.children(".active").removeClass("active"), this.$stage.children(":eq(" + i.join("), :eq(") + ")").addClass("active"), this.$stage.children(".center").removeClass("center"), this.settings.center && this.$stage.children().eq(this.current()).addClass("center")
        }
    }], e.prototype.initialize = function () {
        if (this.enter("initializing"), this.trigger("initialize"), this.$element.toggleClass(this.settings.rtlClass, this.settings.rtl), this.settings.autoWidth && !this.is("pre-loading")) {
            var b, c, e;
            b = this.$element.find("img"), c = this.settings.nestedItemSelector ? "." + this.settings.nestedItemSelector : d, e = this.$element.children(c).width(), b.length && 0 >= e && this.preloadAutoWidthImages(b)
        }
        this.$element.addClass(this.options.loadingClass), this.$stage = a("').wrap(''), this.$element.append(this.$stage.parent()), this.replace(this.$element.children().not(this.$stage.parent())), this.$element.is(":visible") ? this.refresh() : this.invalidate("width"), this.$element.removeClass(this.options.loadingClass).addClass(this.options.loadedClass), this.registerEventHandlers(), this.leave("initializing"), this.trigger("initialized")
    }, e.prototype.setup = function () {
        var b = this.viewport(), c = this.options.responsive, d = -1, e = null;
        c ? (a.each(c, function (a) {
            b >= a && a > d && (d = Number(a))
        }), e = a.extend({}, this.options, c[d]), "function" == typeof e.stagePadding && (e.stagePadding = e.stagePadding()), delete e.responsive, e.responsiveClass && this.$element.attr("class", this.$element.attr("class").replace(new RegExp("(" + this.options.responsiveClass + "-)\\S+\\s", "g"), "$1" + d))) : e = a.extend({}, this.options), this.trigger("change", {
            property: {
                name: "settings",
                value: e
            }
        }), this._breakpoint = d, this.settings = e, this.invalidate("settings"), this.trigger("changed", {
            property: {
                name: "settings",
                value: this.settings
            }
        })
    }, e.prototype.optionsLogic = function () {
        this.settings.autoWidth && (this.settings.stagePadding = !1, this.settings.merge = !1)
    }, e.prototype.prepare = function (b) {
        var c = this.trigger("prepare", {content: b});
        return c.data || (c.data = a("").addClass(this.options.itemClass).append(b)), this.trigger("prepared", {content: c.data}), c.data
    }, e.prototype.update = function () {
        for (var b = 0, c = this._pipe.length, d = a.proxy(function (a) {
            return this[a]
        }, this._invalidated), e = {}; c > b;) (this._invalidated.all || a.grep(this._pipe[b].filter, d).length > 0) && this._pipe[b].run(e), b++;
        this._invalidated = {}, !this.is("valid") && this.enter("valid")
    }, e.prototype.width = function (a) {
        switch (a = a || e.Width.Default) {
            case e.Width.Inner:
            case e.Width.Outer:
                return this._width;
            default:
                return this._width - 2 * this.settings.stagePadding + this.settings.margin
        }
    }, e.prototype.refresh = function () {
        this.enter("refreshing"), this.trigger("refresh"), this.setup(), this.optionsLogic(), this.$element.addClass(this.options.refreshClass), this.update(), this.$element.removeClass(this.options.refreshClass), this.leave("refreshing"), this.trigger("refreshed")
    }, e.prototype.onThrottledResize = function () {
        b.clearTimeout(this.resizeTimer), this.resizeTimer = b.setTimeout(this._handlers.onResize, this.settings.responsiveRefreshRate)
    }, e.prototype.onResize = function () {
        return this._items.length ? this._width === this.$element.width() ? !1 : this.$element.is(":visible") ? (this.enter("resizing"), this.trigger("resize").isDefaultPrevented() ? (this.leave("resizing"), !1) : (this.invalidate("width"), this.refresh(), this.leave("resizing"), void this.trigger("resized"))) : !1 : !1
    }, e.prototype.registerEventHandlers = function () {
        a.support.transition && this.$stage.on(a.support.transition.end + ".owl.core", a.proxy(this.onTransitionEnd, this)), this.settings.responsive !== !1 && this.on(b, "resize", this._handlers.onThrottledResize), this.settings.mouseDrag && (this.$element.addClass(this.options.dragClass), /*this.$stage.on("mousedown.owl.core", a.proxy(this.onDragStart, this)),*/ this.$stage.on("dragstart.owl.core selectstart.owl.core", function () {
            return !1
        })), /*this.settings.touchDrag && */(this.$stage.on("touchstart.owl.core", a.proxy(this.onDragStart, this)), this.$stage.on("touchcancel.owl.core", a.proxy(this.onDragEnd, this)))
    }, e.prototype.onDragStart = function (b) {
        var d = null;
        3 !== b.which && (a.support.transform ? (d = this.$stage.css("transform").replace(/.*\(|\)| /g, "").split(","), d = {
            x: d[16 === d.length ? 12 : 4],
            y: d[16 === d.length ? 13 : 5]
        }) : (d = this.$stage.position(), d = {
            x: this.settings.rtl ? d.left + this.$stage.width() - this.width() + this.settings.margin : d.left,
            y: d.top
        }), this.is("animating") && (a.support.transform ? this.animate(d.x) : this.$stage.stop(), this.invalidate("position")), /*this.$element.toggleClass(this.options.grabClass, "mousedown" === b.type),*/ this.speed(0), this._drag.time = (new Date).getTime(), this._drag.target = a(b.target), this._drag.stage.start = d, this._drag.stage.current = d/*, this._drag.pointer = this.pointer(b)*/, a(c).on("mouseup.owl.core touchend.owl.core", a.proxy(this.onDragEnd, this)), a(c).one("mousemove.owl.core touchmove.owl.core", a.proxy(function (b) {
            var d = this.difference(this._drag.pointer, this.pointer(b));
            a(c).on("mousemove.owl.core touchmove.owl.core", a.proxy(this.onDragMove, this)), Math.abs(d.x)  0 ^ this.settings.rtl ? "left" : "right";
        a(c).off(".owl.core"), this.$element.removeClass(this.options.grabClass), (0 !== d.x && this.is("dragging") || !this.is("valid")) && (this.speed(this.settings.dragEndSpeed || this.settings.smartSpeed), this.current(this.closest(e.x, 0 !== d.x ? f : this._drag.direction)), this.invalidate("position"), this.update(), this._drag.direction = f, (Math.abs(d.x) > 3 || (new Date).getTime() - this._drag.time > 300) && this._drag.target.one("click.owl.core", function () {
            return !1
        })), this.is("dragging") && (this.leave("dragging"), this.trigger("dragged"))
    }, e.prototype.closest = function (b, c) {
        var d = -1, e = 30, f = this.width(), g = this.coordinates();
        return this.settings.freeDrag || a.each(g, a.proxy(function (a, h) {
            return "left" === c && b > h - e && h + e > b ? d = a : "right" === c && b > h - f - e && h - f + e > b ? d = a + 1 : this.op(b, "", g[a + 1] || h - f) && (d = "left" === c ? a + 1 : a), -1 === d
        }, this)), this.settings.loop || (this.op(b, ">", g[this.minimum()]) ? d = b = this.minimum() : this.op(b, " 0;
        this.is("animating") && this.onTransitionEnd(), c && (this.enter("animating"), this.trigger("translate")), a.support.transform3d && a.support.transition ? this.$stage.css({
            transform: "translate3d(" + b + "px,0px,0px)",
            transition: this.speed() / 1e3 + "s"
        }) : c ? this.$stage.animate({left: b + "px"}, this.speed(), this.settings.fallbackEasing, a.proxy(this.onTransitionEnd, this)) : this.$stage.css({left: b + "px"})
    }, e.prototype.is = function (a) {
        return this._states.current[a] && this._states.current[a] > 0
    }, e.prototype.current = function (a) {
        if (a === d) return this._current;
        if (0 === this._items.length) return d;
        if (a = this.normalize(a), this._current !== a) {
            var b = this.trigger("change", {property: {name: "position", value: a}});
            b.data !== d && (a = this.normalize(b.data)), this._current = a, this.invalidate("position"), this.trigger("changed", {
                property: {
                    name: "position",
                    value: this._current
                }
            })
        }
        return this._current
    }, e.prototype.invalidate = function (b) {
        return "string" === a.type(b) && (this._invalidated[b] = !0, this.is("valid") && this.leave("valid")), a.map(this._invalidated, function (a, b) {
            return b
        })
    }, e.prototype.reset = function (a) {
        a = this.normalize(a), a !== d && (this._speed = 0, this._current = a, this.suppress(["translate", "translated"]), this.animate(this.coordinates(a)), this.release(["translate", "translated"]))
    }, e.prototype.normalize = function (a, b) {
        var c = this._items.length, e = b ? 0 : this._clones.length;
        return !this.isNumeric(a) || 1 > c ? a = d : (0 > a || a >= c + e) && (a = ((a - e / 2) % c + c) % c + e / 2), a
    }, e.prototype.relative = function (a) {
        return a -= this._clones.length / 2, this.normalize(a, !0)
    }, e.prototype.maximum = function (a) {
        var b, c, d, e = this.settings, f = this._coordinates.length;
        if (e.loop) f = this._clones.length / 2 + this._items.length - 1; else if (e.autoWidth || e.merge) {
            if (b = this._items.length) for (c = this._items[--b].width(), d = this.$element.width(); b-- && (c += this._items[b].width() + this.settings.margin, !(c > d));) ;
            f = b + 1
        } else f = e.center ? this._items.length - 1 : this._items.length - e.items;
        return a && (f -= this._clones.length / 2), Math.max(f, 0)
    }, e.prototype.minimum = function (a) {
        return a ? 0 : this._clones.length / 2
    }, e.prototype.items = function (a) {
        return a === d ? this._items.slice() : (a = this.normalize(a, !0), this._items[a])
    }, e.prototype.mergers = function (a) {
        return a === d ? this._mergers.slice() : (a = this.normalize(a, !0), this._mergers[a])
    }, e.prototype.clones = function (b) {
        var c = this._clones.length / 2, e = c + this._items.length, f = function (a) {
            return a % 2 === 0 ? e + a / 2 : c - (a + 1) / 2
        };
        return b === d ? a.map(this._clones, function (a, b) {
            return f(b)
        }) : a.map(this._clones, function (a, c) {
            return a === b ? f(c) : null
        })
    }, e.prototype.speed = function (a) {
        return a !== d && (this._speed = a), this._speed
    }, e.prototype.coordinates = function (b) {
        var c, e = 1, f = b - 1;
        return b === d ? a.map(this._coordinates, a.proxy(function (a, b) {
            return this.coordinates(b)
        }, this)) : (this.settings.center ? (this.settings.rtl && (e = -1, f = b + 1), c = this._coordinates[b], c += (this.width() - c + (this._coordinates[f] || 0)) / 2 * e) : c = this._coordinates[f] || 0, c = Math.ceil(c))
    }, e.prototype.duration = function (a, b, c) {
        return 0 === c ? 0 : Math.min(Math.max(Math.abs(b - a), 1), 6) * Math.abs(c || this.settings.smartSpeed)
    }, e.prototype.to = function (a, b) {
        var c = this.current(), d = null, e = a - this.relative(c), f = (e > 0) - (0 > e), g = this._items.length,
            h = this.minimum(), i = this.maximum();
        this.settings.loop ? (!this.settings.rewind && Math.abs(e) > g / 2 && (e += -1 * f * g), a = c + e, d = ((a - h) % g + g) % g + h, d !== a && i >= d - e && d - e > 0 && (c = d - e, a = d, this.reset(c))) : this.settings.rewind ? (i += 1, a = (a % i + i) % i) : a = Math.max(h, Math.min(i, a)), this.speed(this.duration(c, a, b)), this.current(a), this.$element.is(":visible") && this.update()
    }, e.prototype.next = function (a) {
        a = a || !1, this.to(this.relative(this.current()) + 1, a)
    }, e.prototype.prev = function (a) {
        a = a || !1, this.to(this.relative(this.current()) - 1, a)
    }, e.prototype.onTransitionEnd = function (a) {
        return a !== d && (a.stopPropagation(), (a.target || a.srcElement || a.originalTarget) !== this.$stage.get(0)) ? !1 : (this.leave("animating"), void this.trigger("translated"))
    }, e.prototype.viewport = function () {
        var d;
        return this.options.responsiveBaseElement !== b ? d = a(this.options.responsiveBaseElement).width() : b.innerWidth ? d = b.innerWidth : c.documentElement && c.documentElement.clientWidth ? d = c.documentElement.clientWidth : console.warn("Can not detect viewport width."), d
    }, e.prototype.replace = function (b) {
        this.$stage.empty(), this._items = [], b && (b = b instanceof jQuery ? b : a(b)), this.settings.nestedItemSelector && (b = b.find("." + this.settings.nestedItemSelector)), b.filter(function () {
            return 1 === this.nodeType
        }).each(a.proxy(function (a, b) {
            b = this.prepare(b), this.$stage.append(b), this._items.push(b), this._mergers.push(1 * b.find("[data-merge]").addBack("[data-merge]").attr("data-merge") || 1)
        }, this)), this.reset(this.isNumeric(this.settings.startPosition) ? this.settings.startPosition : 0), this.invalidate("items")
    }, e.prototype.add = function (b, c) {
        var e = this.relative(this._current);
        c = c === d ? this._items.length : this.normalize(c, !0), b = b instanceof jQuery ? b : a(b), this.trigger("add", {
            content: b,
            position: c
        }), b = this.prepare(b), 0 === this._items.length || c === this._items.length ? (0 === this._items.length && this.$stage.append(b), 0 !== this._items.length && this._items[c - 1].after(b), this._items.push(b), this._mergers.push(1 * b.find("[data-merge]").addBack("[data-merge]").attr("data-merge") || 1)) : (this._items[c].before(b), this._items.splice(c, 0, b), this._mergers.splice(c, 0, 1 * b.find("[data-merge]").addBack("[data-merge]").attr("data-merge") || 1)), this._items[e] && this.reset(this._items[e].index()), this.invalidate("items"), this.trigger("added", {
            content: b,
            position: c
        })
    }, e.prototype.remove = function (a) {
        a = this.normalize(a, !0), a !== d && (this.trigger("remove", {
            content: this._items[a],
            position: a
        }), this._items[a].remove(), this._items.splice(a, 1), this._mergers.splice(a, 1), this.invalidate("items"), this.trigger("removed", {
            content: null,
            position: a
        }))
    }, e.prototype.preloadAutoWidthImages = function (b) {
        b.each(a.proxy(function (b, c) {
            this.enter("pre-loading"), c = a(c), a(new Image).one("load", a.proxy(function (a) {
                c.attr("src", a.target.src), c.css("opacity", 1), this.leave("pre-loading"), !this.is("pre-loading") && !this.is("initializing") && this.refresh()
            }, this)).attr("src", c.attr("src") || c.attr("data-src") || c.attr("data-src-retina"))
        }, this))
    }, e.prototype.destroy = function () {
        this.$element.off(".owl.core"), this.$stage.off(".owl.core"), a(c).off(".owl.core"), this.settings.responsive !== !1 && (b.clearTimeout(this.resizeTimer), this.off(b, "resize", this._handlers.onThrottledResize));
        for (var d in this._plugins) this._plugins[d].destroy();
        this.$stage.children(".cloned").remove(), this.$stage.unwrap(), this.$stage.children().contents().unwrap(), this.$stage.children().unwrap(), this.$stage.remove(), this.$element.removeClass(this.options.refreshClass).removeClass(this.options.loadingClass).removeClass(this.options.loadedClass).removeClass(this.options.rtlClass).removeClass(this.options.dragClass).removeClass(this.options.grabClass).attr("class", this.$element.attr("class").replace(new RegExp(this.options.responsiveClass + "-\\S+\\s", "g"), "")).removeData("owl.carousel")
    }, e.prototype.op = function (a, b, c) {
        var d = this.settings.rtl;
        switch (b) {
            case" c : c > a;
            case">":
                return d ? c > a : a > c;
            case">=":
                return d ? c >= a : a >= c;
            case"= c : c >= a
        }
    }, e.prototype.on = function (a, b, c, d) {
        a.addEventListener ? a.addEventListener(b, c, d) : a.attachEvent && a.attachEvent("on" + b, c)
    }, e.prototype.off = function (a, b, c, d) {
        a.removeEventListener ? a.removeEventListener(b, c, d) : a.detachEvent && a.detachEvent("on" + b, c)
    }, e.prototype.trigger = function (b, c, d, f, g) {
        var h = {item: {count: this._items.length, index: this.current()}},
            i = a.camelCase(a.grep(["on", b, d], function (a) {
                return a
            }).join("-").toLowerCase()),
            j = a.Event([b, "owl", d || "carousel"].join(".").toLowerCase(), a.extend({relatedTarget: this}, h, c));
        return this._supress[b] || (a.each(this._plugins, function (a, b) {
            b.onTrigger && b.onTrigger(j)
        }), this.register({
            type: e.Type.Event,
            name: b
        }), this.$element.trigger(j), this.settings && "function" == typeof this.settings[i] && this.settings[i].call(this, j)), j
    }, e.prototype.enter = function (b) {
        a.each([b].concat(this._states.tags[b] || []), a.proxy(function (a, b) {
            this._states.current[b] === d && (this._states.current[b] = 0), this._states.current[b]++
        }, this))
    }, e.prototype.leave = function (b) {
        a.each([b].concat(this._states.tags[b] || []), a.proxy(function (a, b) {
            this._states.current[b]--
        }, this))
    }, e.prototype.register = function (b) {
        if (b.type === e.Type.Event) {
            if (a.event.special[b.name] || (a.event.special[b.name] = {}), !a.event.special[b.name].owl) {
                var c = a.event.special[b.name]._default;
                a.event.special[b.name]._default = function (a) {
                    return !c || !c.apply || a.namespace && -1 !== a.namespace.indexOf("owl") ? a.namespace && a.namespace.indexOf("owl") > -1 : c.apply(this, arguments)
                }, a.event.special[b.name].owl = !0
            }
        } else b.type === e.Type.State && (this._states.tags[b.name] ? this._states.tags[b.name] = this._states.tags[b.name].concat(b.tags) : this._states.tags[b.name] = b.tags, this._states.tags[b.name] = a.grep(this._states.tags[b.name], a.proxy(function (c, d) {
            return a.inArray(c, this._states.tags[b.name]) === d
        }, this)))
    }, e.prototype.suppress = function (b) {
        a.each(b, a.proxy(function (a, b) {
            this._supress[b] = !0
        }, this))
    }, e.prototype.release = function (b) {
        a.each(b, a.proxy(function (a, b) {
            delete this._supress[b]
        }, this))
    }, e.prototype.pointer = function (a) {
        var c = {x: null, y: null};
        return a = a.originalEvent || a || b.event, a = a.touches && a.touches.length ? a.touches[0] : a.changedTouches && a.changedTouches.length ? a.changedTouches[0] : a, a.pageX ? (c.x = a.pageX, c.y = a.pageY) : (c.x = a.clientX, c.y = a.clientY), c
    }, e.prototype.isNumeric = function (a) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(a))
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema parece que está en la clase `.owl-drag`, que es la que te está ocasionando ese comportamiento no deseado. Al quitarla del `section` que es el padre del **carousel** ha dejado de reproducirse el problema.

Tras comprobar eso, me he ido a la parte del código que parece ser la encargada de generar las propiedades que tendrá el objeto `owl-carousel` y he detectado que hay una propiedad cuyo valor tiene la clase que nos está molestando, `dragClass: "owl-drag"`:

```
 e.Defaults = {
        items: 3,
        loop: !1,
        center: !1,
        rewind: !1,
        mouseDrag: !0,
        touchDrag: !0,
        pullDrag: !0,
        freeDrag: !1,
        margin: 0,
        stagePadding: 0,
        merge: !1,
        mergeFit: !0,
        autoWidth: !1,
        startPosition: 0,
        rtl: !1,
        smartSpeed: 250,
        fluidSpeed: !1,
        dragEndSpeed: !1,
        responsive: {},
        responsiveRefreshRate: 200,
        responsiveBaseElement: b,
        fallbackEasing: "swing",
        info: !1,
        nestedItemSelector: !1,
        itemElement: "div",
        stageElement: "div",
        refreshClass: "owl-refresh",
        loadedClass: "owl-loaded",
        loadingClass: "owl-loading",
        rtlClass: "owl-rtl",
        responsiveClass: "owl-responsive",
        /*dragClass: "owl-drag",*/
        itemClass: "owl-item",
        stageClass: "owl-stage",
        stageOuterClass: "owl-stage-outer",
        grabClass: "owl-grab"
    },
```

Prueba a comentar esa línea del código, que tiene pinta de que con eso debería valerte.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ese era el error.

Comment: La mejor manera de agradecer es puntuar la respuesta y darla como válida, así cualquiera que visite la pregunta podrá saber que se obtuvo una solución al problema ^^